# Select From multiple tables and relate with COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, mysql-workbench

first sorry, i don't have fluid english.

I want select 3 rows in 3 different tables, two of them without Foreing Key/relation.

Need to select amount of customers in each store, and total amount of payments in these stores in one query.

Here are the tables:

Customers

[image: customer table]

Stores

[image: store table]

Payments

[image: payment table]

I have tried these querys to get payments for each store and customers for each store, but don't know how can unify in one query:

Payments/store

```
SELECT count(a.payment_id) as alquileres, b.store_id 
FROM customer b, payment a
WHERE a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
GROUP BY b.store_id;
```

customers/store

```
SELECT count(customer_id), store_id 
FROM customer
GROUP BY store_id;
```

But when I add count(customer_id) in unique query don't have same results.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one query:

```
select c.store_id,
       count(distinct c.customer_id) as num_customers,
       count(p.payment_id) as num_payments
from customers c left join
     payments p
     on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.store_id;
```